# Out of Memory EC2 Ubuntu Apache Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, memory, memory-management, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

My memory, including swap, was at capacity.  I could no longer SSH into my server, it would either take a very long time (30+mins) or I would give up waiting.  When it did connect, it was very slow.

To remedy this, I upgraded my AWS EC2 instance from t1.micro to m3.medium from the AWS management console.

After stopping the instance, upgrading, and restarting the instance, it says that it is running smoothly.  However, my site is still down and I can not SSH into it.

Do I need to reboot Ubuntu for it to recognize the instance upgrade?  Did upgrading the instance size not help?

```
sudo lshw -class memory
 *-memory                
       description: System memory
       physical id: 0
       size: 588MiB
```

Comment: try this command to see if the memory is recognized `sudo lshw -class memory`

Comment: *-memory                
       description: System memory
       physical id: 0
       size: 588MiB

Comment: Try rebooting the system, the promised 3,7GB of memory is clearly not recognized.